# Motivation for different parameter passing semantics between languages

Tags: parameter-passing, programming-languages

C++, Java and Javascript, and Python and Ruby all have different semantics regarding parameter passing.

C++ gives users the choice of passing by reference and value with "&" syntax. Java and Javascript pass by value of reference for objects, and value for primitives. Python and Ruby has its pass by "name and object" semantics, out of a lack of better terminology. Other languages I'm less familiar with, I'm sure, have more semantic categories to throw into the mix.

This is all understandable, but appears somewhat arbitrary as just facts-to-memorize without understanding how the different semantics derive from the design philosophy of the respective languages.

What design decisions or historical background motivate the different parameter passing semantics in each of these languages?

Comment: "Java and Javascript pass by value of reference for objects, and value for primitives. Python and Ruby has its pass by "name and object" semantics, out of a lack of better terminology." Java, JavaScript, Python, and Ruby have the exact same semantics for passing and assigning.

Comment: Most accounts of Python and Ruby parameter passing I've seen distinguish mutable and immutable objects. Am I understanding the claim in your comment correctly, that this concept is in all cases functionally equivalent to the "pass by value of reference" explanation given for Java/ Javascript?

Comment: It has nothing to do with "functional" equivalence. The semantics are identical in every way and should be described identically.